# Do bonuses against Opportunity Attacks stack?

Tags: dnd-4e, opportunity-attack

I have started playing a halfling rogue. His racial bonus to AC against Opportunity Attacks is +2. Because he is an Artful Dodger he also has a class feature of adding his CHA MOD (which is +5) to his AC against 'Opportunity Attacks.

So would these bonuses stack, giving him a +7 to OA, or would it just be a +5?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Yes, they stack**

Because they are different types of bonuses (racial, and untyped).

Remember also that untyped bonuses always stack *unless they come from the same game element*.
That is, if your halfling rogue is within 5 squares of an [Ardent](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/class.aspx?id=529)<sup>DDI</sup> ally with Wisdom 16 and the Mantle of Clarity feature, he takes an additional +3 (untyped) bonus to his AC against opportunity attacks (totaling a +10).
But, if your character is within 5 squares of two allied Ardents, one with Wisdom 16 and one with Wisdom 19, he would receive "only" an additional +4 to AC vs. opportunity attacks, because the two Mantles of Clarity don't stack and only the strongest is used.

For reference:

> **Mantle of Clarity**
>   You and each ally within 5 squares of you gain a bonus to all defenses against opportunity attacks. The bonus equals your Wisdom modifier. In addition...

Comment: I think Erik is also trying to get at that the biggest non-stacking bonuses in general are feats. If you take light blade expertise and then versatile expertise (light blade) you will only get one feat based bonus to hit. Works the same for everything else, but feats are like 90 percent of where this might happen.